# How to get file_id of file uploaded in Grid field

Tags: grid, files

I have a grid field with rows containing files uploaded.
These grid entries are output on a standard page but I need to access the filetype of the files uploaded and this only appears to be available in a '{exp:file:entries}' tag pair.
How can I access the file_id of the uploaded files in each row of the grid field in order to use a tag like
`{exp:file:entries file_id="grid-row-file-id"}{filetype}{/exp:file:entries}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried a [variable pair](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/file.html#variable-pair-usage) and the [`{file_id}`](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/file.html#file-id) variable inside it? But, by this way, you already have access to the mime type, using the [`{mime_type}`](https://docs.expressionengine.com/latest/fieldtypes/file.html#mime-type) variable.

```
{gallery}
    <figure>
        {gallery:image}
            <img src="{url}" height="{height}" width="{width}">
            <figcaption>mime type of file {file_id}: {mime_type}</figcaption>
        {/gallery:image}
    </figure>
{/gallery}
```

Comment: That's brilliant - I didn't know you could use the grid row as a tag pair inside the main grid field tag pair!

Comment: I've tried this in 3.4.3 and it doesn't work. Within a grid the opening {gallery:image} tag is rendered as the image URL. I don't think it's possible to get the meta data of the file when it's within a grid unfortunately.

Comment: @CraigDuarte, this looks like a bug to me.

Comment: @RobsonSobral you're right, this was a bug with 3.4.3, fine in 3.4.4. Thanks!